# Trying to connect to my SFTP linux machine

Tags: sftp

I've tried to connect to my Linux machine running SFTP, but when I try to connect via my Windows 10 machine with cmd it says:

```
sftp_user@<IPAddress>'s password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password)
Authenticated to <IPAddress> ([<IPAddress>]:22)
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requestion no-more-sessions@openssh.com
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
Connection closed
```

can you please help me, what's wrong?

Comment: The password authentication is successful according to the debug message, but the session seems to be ending as soon as it begins. You might want to check the logs on the Linux machine: if there is something wrong with the account setup e.g. overly lax permissions or something else the `sshd` does not like, there should be a clear log message about it.

Comment: Does this sftp_user account have any special configuration in the ssh server's sshd_config file? Is it subject to a chrootDirectory, for example? Please [edit] your question to include any special configuration in the linux system's sshd_config file for SFTP.

Comment: On the server there will probably be log messages explaining the reason for closing the connection. I'd start with `/var/log/auth.log`